# Is it possible to bound Mertens function $M(n)$ from an inclusion-exclusion formulation?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, lower-bounds, upper-bounds

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4685049/formula-for-mertens-function-m-leftx-right-in-terms-of-the-prime-counting-fu) I proposed a formulation of Mertens function $M(n)$ using the inclusion-exclusion principle, as follows:

$$M(n)=-\pi\left(n\right)+\left(\sum_{p_{i}<\sqrt{n}}\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}}\rfloor\right)\right)-\left(\sum_{p_{i}<p_{j}<\sqrt[3]{n}}\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}p_{j}}\rfloor\right)\right)+\left(\sum_{p_{i}<p_{j}<p_{k}<\sqrt[4]{n}}\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}p_{j}p_{k}}\rfloor\right)\right)-\dots-\left(\frac{\pi\left(\sqrt{n}\right)^{2}+\pi\left(\sqrt{n}\right)}{2}\right)+\sum_{i=3}^{j}\left(\left(-1\right)^{i+1}\left(\frac{\left(\pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)-\left(i-2\right)\right)\left(\pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)-\left(i-3\right)\right)\left(2\left(\pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)-\left(i-2\right)\right)+3\left(i-2\right)+1\right)}{6}\right)\right)$$

Where $j=\max\{i\mid \pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)>i-2\}$

The advantages of this formulation are that (i) the terms $-\pi\left(n\right)+\left(\sum_{p_{i}<\sqrt{n}}\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}}\rfloor\right)\right)-\left(\sum_{p_{i}<p_{j}<\sqrt[3]{n}}\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}p_{j}}\rfloor\right)\right)+\left(\sum_{p_{i}<p_{j}<p_{k}<\sqrt[4]{n}}\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}p_{j}p_{k}}\rfloor\right)\right)-\dots$ seem pretty similar to [Legendre's Formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendresFormula.html) and (ii) the terms $-\left(\frac{\pi\left(\sqrt{n}\right)^{2}+\pi\left(\sqrt{n}\right)}{2}\right)+\sum_{i=3}^{j}\left(\left(-1\right)^{i+1}\left(\frac{\left(\pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)-\left(i-2\right)\right)\left(\pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)-\left(i-3\right)\right)\left(2\left(\pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)-\left(i-2\right)\right)+3\left(i-2\right)+1\right)}{6}\right)\right)$ seem boundable.

I would like to assess how "similar" are the terms in (i) to Legendre's formula, and if the similarity is enough to bound them sharply; and how "boundable" could be the terms in (ii). Obviously I expect to be difficult finding sharp bounds, as bounding sharply $M(n)$ could prove/disprove the Riemmann Hypothesis; but maybe this approach has not been explored (I doubt it, so any reference in this sense would be welcomed too).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

As noted by @StevenClark the formula needs to incorporate a $1$ to account for $1$, and the sums in (i) must consider primes less **or equal** than $\sqrt[i]{n}$; thus, the completed formula would be:

$$M(n)=1-\pi\left(n\right)+\left(\sum_{p_{i}\leq\sqrt{n}}\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}}\rfloor\right)\right)-\left(\sum_{p_{i}<p_{j}\leq\sqrt[3]{n}}\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}p_{j}}\rfloor\right)\right)+\left(\sum_{p_{i}<p_{j}<p_{k}\leq\sqrt[4]{n}}\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}p_{j}p_{k}}\rfloor\right)\right)-\dots-\left(\frac{\pi\left(\sqrt{n}\right)^{2}+\pi\left(\sqrt{n}\right)}{2}\right)+\sum_{i=3}^{j}\left(\left(-1\right)^{i+1}\left(\frac{\left(\pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)-\left(i-2\right)\right)\left(\pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)-\left(i-3\right)\right)\left(2\left(\pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)-\left(i-2\right)\right)+3\left(i-2\right)+1\right)}{6}\right)\right)$$

Where $j=\max\{i\mid \pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)>i-2\}$

**EDIT 2**

After analyzing the flaws detected by @StevenClark, I have found a way to fix them, but the formula changes are substantial. Here it goes:

$$M(n)=1-\pi\left(n\right)+\sum_{p_{i}\leq\frac{n}{p_i}}\left(\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}}\rfloor\right)-i\right)-\sum_{p_{i}<p_{j}\leq\frac{n}{p_ip_j}}\left(\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}p_{j}}\rfloor\right)-j\right)+\sum_{p_{i}<p_{j}<p_{k}\leq\frac{n}{p_ip_jp_k}}\left(\pi\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i}p_{j}p_{k}}\rfloor\right)-k\right)-\dots$$

Indeed, the formula looks cleaner and even more beautiful.

Comment: TeX note: $M\left(n\right)$ `M\left(n\right)` produces unusual spacing.  At least to me, $M(n)$ `M(n)` looks better.  If you regularly need the sizing effect, you can also do $M{\left(n\right)}$ `M{\left(n\right)}`.

Comment: @LSpice thanks for the tip, edited!

Comment: Could you please clarify $j=\max\{i\mid \pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)>i-2\}$? I don't understand in $\sum\limits_{i=3}^j$ how the upper limit $j$ can be a function of the sum index variable $i$, or how $>i−2$ is applied since this implies a Boolean result of true or false.

Comment: @StevenClark basically the terms in (i) stop generating when $\pi\left(\sqrt[i]{n}\right)<i-1$; therefore, the terms in (ii) need to stop generating at this point to avoid "overexclusion".

Comment: I can't seem to valid your formula even for the first case $M(1)=1$. All of the $\pi()$ functions evaluate to zero and we're left with the sum $\sum\limits_{i=3}^j (-1)^{i+1}  \frac{((i-3) (i-2) (i-1))}{6}$ which never seems to evaluate to $1$ for any value of $j$.

Comment: @StevenClark you are right, I have edited the OP to account for $1$, as it was not evaluated. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the next counterexample is at $n=9$ where I believe $j=2$ and so the exclusion term evaluates to zero and $1-\pi (9)+\pi \left(\frac{9}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi\left(\sqrt{9}\right)^2+\pi\left(\sqrt{9}\right)}{2}=-4$ which is inconsistent with $M(9)=-2$.

Comment: @StevenClark you are right, thanks for pointing it out; the sums in (i) must consider primes less **or equal** than $\sqrt[i]{n}$, I have edited accordingly

Comment: Unless my calculations are incorrect, I believe the next exception is now at $n=70$ where $M(70)=-2$ and your newly revised formula evaluates to $-1$.

Comment: @StevenClark true, the formula is incorrect, this time no easy fixing possible. Thanks for taking your time finding the flaws!

Comment: @StevenClark I think I have found a way to "fix" the formula (it looks rather different, but surprisingly much simpler). I have performed a random testing and seems to be valid.

Comment: Congratulations, I think you may have finally gotten it! I found no counterexamples when testing your formula up to $n=1000$ with the Mathematica function
$$\text{Mtest[n_]:=1-PrimePi[n]-Sum[MoebiusMu[k](PrimePi[n/k]-primeIndex[FactorInteger[k][[PrimeNu[k],1]]]),{k,Select[Range[2,n],FactorInteger[#][[PrimeNu[#],1]]<=n/#&]}]}$$

where the function $\text{primeIndex}$ is defined as

$$\text{primeIndex[p_]:=Block[{i=Floor[LogIntegral[p]],delta=1},If[p<Prime[i],delta=-1];While[p!=Prime[i],i+=delta];i]}$$

Comment: But note the function $\text{Mtest[n]}$ involves the $\text{MoebiusMu[k]}$ function and is much more complicated than the reference function

$$\text{M[n_]:=Sum[MoebiusMu[k],{k,1,n}]}$$

Comment: @StevenClark thanks! I agree that the correct formula does not seem really tractable or useful at first sight... anyway, another way to express $M(n)$